# Replace TimThumb in existing WordPress Themes

Tags: customization, timthumb, thumbnails

I'm sure most are aware of the most recent Timthumb issues. I know they have put a band-aid on the problem, but I really don't care for the script for several reasons. Before I started building my themes I purchased several from various markets. I'm trying to figure out the best method for removing Timthumb and replacing it with something else.

I've successfully replaced it for one theme using the_post_thumbnail, but it was quite a bit of work. I'm just curious if someone knows of a better method. As it stands now, I have to weigh the time it will take using my method vs. how much do I actually like the theme. Can you provide any suggestions or links to proven articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options here:

### Use `the_post_thumbnail()`

You say you've already done this with one theme.  This is really the best solution because it keeps everything using core code (which is frequently updated) rather than third-party libraries.

### Upgrade TimThumb

Since the "most recent" issues, they've released a new version of TimThumb that corrects the security vulnerabilities.  Merely replacing the old system with [the updated, secure one](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) should be the quickest path to resolution.

### Email the developer

If you're using freely-available themes, you're out of luck and might be stuck fixing things yourself.  If you actually purchased the themes from someone else, please email them and ask that they release an update.

It's not really their responsibility to provide a security update, but most quality developers will jump at the chance to update their code to prevent huge security holes.  Besides, it never hurts to ask.

Comment: The themes I'm speaking of are from ThemeForest, Elegant Themes (they've removed Timthumb from the themes I believe. It shows up as an option in the sample data, but it must be old sample data?). Other themes are from Themify and a few other places that had deals on AppSumo. Most have updated the themes to latest version of Timthumb, but like I've said I still want to remove the script. I assumed the_post_thumbnail was the best route, but I wanted to check if there was a quicker way. When I updated the one theme I ended up reloading all images manually. Guess it's that or nothing. Thanks

Comment: Also, I don't buy themes now, I build my own, but when I did use others themes I paid. I would never use one of the "free" rip-off sites that rip off theme developers. If anyone has ever built their own, they know it's a very small price to pay vs. the work and effort. Sometimes I get more work than I can handle and might choose to use a pre-built theme is why I am looking for the best solution. Again thanks for your input. I'll leave it open for another day to see if anyone else has any input, then I'll close. Regards, Jeremy Jared